# What areas of mathematics will help me in creating this add-on?

Tags: python, add-on, edges, mathematics, development

I want to create an add-on like this. It edits the selected edge, adds vertices to it ( as much as you need - the parameter will be adjusted  ), creates the curvature we want.

I want to make this add-on to better understand math, blender and python.

I think I can still deal with Blender and Python. But how can I do exactly what I planned with the help of mathematics - it's hard to say, I'm not very good at mathematics.

Therefore, the question is - **What topics in mathematics should I study in order to understand how to make this add-on?**

[image: Preview]

Comment: This seems to be reinventing the wheel into a more limited wheel. Additionally, the curve profile widget is already available within blender, so you would probably not be doing much mathematics.

Comment: I think you'll be fine with arithmetic, algebra, geometry and trigonometry.